IDbContextFactory for console app and blazor
I have a little problem with DbContext and DbContextFactory.
I created a class library to store all the queries to access the database.
I want to use that library inside a Blazor App and a Console App.
So, for Blazor there is no problem; I can create a Dependency Injection for the DbContextFactory. I have a problem with the console app.
To resolve my problem, I inserted all the necessary methods to get the DbContextFactory inside the constructor. It works, but I'm not sure it is a good solution.
Any ideas?
/// <summary>
/// Dtabase Context Factory
/// </summary>
//private readonly SalesContext _db;

private readonly IDbContextFactory<SalesContext> _dbContextFactory;


/// <summary>
/// Ctor for Blazor
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dbContextFactory">Dependency injection</param>
public SalesAccessService(IDbContextFactory<SalesContext> dbContextFactory)
{
    _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
}


public SalesAccessService()
{
    IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
    string? conn = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionSales");
    if (conn == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Not found connection string DefaultConnectionSales inside appsettings.json");
    }

    var services = new ServiceCollection().AddDbContextFactory<SalesContext>(options =>
    options.UseMySQL(conn));

    using (var scope = services.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope())
    {
        _dbContextFactory = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<SalesContext>>();
    }

}


public async Task<ClusterReport?> Test()
{
    await using(var db = await _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync()){
        return await db.ClusterReport.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
}


Why not use Dependency Injection in the console application as well?

Remove the parameterless public SalesAccessService() constructor: the whole point of DI is so that individual services don't do silly things like perform disk IO in a ctor to load config data.

The using (var scope = services.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope()) part is also superfluous: your IDbContextFactory<> will be registered as a singleton, not scoped - so you should use the root container for that.
